# Why the flex-basis of a child element is applied vertically if it has flex-flow: row nowrap?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a parent element with class `.primary` and `flex-flow: column nowrap;` that grows fullwidth;

Then I've set a child element with class `.aaa` that applies a `flex-flow: row nowrap;` and sets growth to 0, shrinking to 1, and flex basis to `10rem`;

But Although it has `flex-flow: row nowrap;` the `flex-basis` is applied to the `y-axis` instead of the `x-axis`. Why ?

```css
.primary {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background: green;
}
.aaa {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  flex: 0 1 10rem;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="primary">
  <div class="aaa">
    <article>
      article  
    </article>
    <aside>
      aside
    </aside>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `flex` property applies to the children of a flex container.

So in this rule:

```
.primary {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    background: green;
}
```

... the `flex` property is doing nothing. The parent (`body`) is not a flex container.

And in this rule:

```
.aaa {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    flex: 0 1 12rem;
    background: red;
}
```

... `.aaa` is the child of `.primary`, which is a column-direction flex container. Therefore, the `flex` property is working along the Y-axis.